# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So, I'm attempting to pass a user's ip address in my app, as follows:

pages/Item.js

```html
const Item = props => (
  <div>
    <SingleItem id={props.query.id} userIP={props.userIP} />
  </div>
);

Item.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const userIP = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
  return { userIP }
}

export default withAmp(Item, { hybrid: true });
```

but get the above mentioned error message (See attached image) when navigating to the page. But if I then do a hard reload of the page the ip details are correctly displayed to the page.

What am I overlooking here and is there a better way to achieve this, for example obtaining the ip address from headers in `_document.js`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req` will only be available when `getInitialProps` is called on the server. This is why it works when you do a refresh on the page.

When navigating to the page there is no server render so `getInitialProps` will be called on the client. Therefore, `req` will be undefined.

You can wrap the assignment in a condition to check if `req` is defined to prevent the error:

```
Item.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  let userIP
  if (req) {
    userIP = req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
  }
  return { userIP }
}
```

However, if you want to have `userIP` available on every page, regardless of whether it's server or client rendered, then you will need to find a way to store it on first load, whichever page that may be.

Perhaps you could store it using **context**.

There is am example of using context here:
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-context-api

I hope this helps.